# D3.js: Having some problems understanding the delay-call functionality and chaining in Bostock's sortable bar chart example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to use transitions and luckily Bostock had made an example which I could use in my own charts.
The problem is that I don't completely understand the syntax and I don't know whether it is some Javascript that I can't figure out or something with D3.js's method chaining:

The original example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705

The part I used:

```
var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };
```

The way I used it (I slightly modified the delay function to "delayF" so that I myself has it easier to see what is what):

```
var transition = myChart.transition().duration(750),
    delayF = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

transition.selectAll("circle")
    .delay(delayF)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { 
     return xScale(d.endedA); })
    .attr("cy", function (d)
    {
        return yScale(d["Duration (min)"]);
    })
```

What I don't understand is the

```
...duration(750),
            delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };
```

Where he somehow chains a function to the other methods, or how you should express it.

I tried modifying it to see if I could better understand it and this worked (the delayF-function is put right in the delay-method):

```
var transition = myChart.transition().duration(750);

        transition.selectAll("circle")
            .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 50; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { 
             return xScale(d.endedA); })
            .attr("cy", function (d)
            {
                return yScale(d["Duration (min)"]);
            })
```

This however didn't (the delayF as its own function without the comma between it and the previous methods:

```
var transition = myChart.transition().duration(750);
        delayF = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

        console.log(delayF);

    transition.selectAll("circle")
        .delay(delayF)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { 
         return xScale(d.endedA); })
        .attr("cy", function (d)
        {
            return yScale(d["Duration (min)"]);
        })
```

(Error: delayF is not defined)

Apparently data ends up missing from the function which it somehow gets if it is chained with a comma to the the transition variable, but "how" is something I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this:

```
var transition = myChart.transition().duration(750),
delayF = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };
```

Is the same of:

```
var transition = myChart.transition().duration(750);
var delayF = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };
```

Therefore, it's just a combined `var` statement, nothing new here.

Besides that, when you said that *"this however didn't work"*...

```
var transition = svg.transition().duration(750);
delayF = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };
```

... you probably made another mistake somewhere else, because it works: the only difference is that now `delayF` is a global.

Here is the modified bl.ocks showing that it works, look at line 122: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/41f9beb431956ee825fb0417c497caec

My guess is that you got that error (`delayF is not defined`) because you forgot to change `delay` to `delayF` in the axis transition, further down.

Comment: Thanks! The truth was more embarrassing than that. I hadn't defined "delayF" so "var delayF..." fixed it.

Regarding Bostock's syntaxs using the comma I still don't understand its functionality. Is it Javascript or is it D3.js? Trying to look for "comma" in either gives me results about parsing data containing commas so I don't seem to find the answers.